# Creating a Cursor in LOVE

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm new to coding and recently started learning about having code located outside of main.lua, which I wanted to do for my custom cursor. The original correctly displayed "cursor.png", but the modified version simply displays the standard cursor. Could someone explain what I'm missing or doing wrong?

#### Original:

```lua
love.load = function()
  cursor = love.graphics.newImage("assets/sprites/cursor.png")
  love.mouse.setVisible(false)
end

love.draw = function()
  love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
  love.graphics.draw(cursor, love.mouse.getX(), love.mouse.getY())
end
```

#### Modified:

```lua
local load = function(cursor)
  love.mouse.setVisible(false)
  local inst = {}
    inst.cursor = love.graphics.newImage("assets/sprites/cursor.png")
  return inst
end

local draw = function(color, image)
  local inst = {}
  inst.color = love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
  inst.image = love.graphics.draw(cursor, love.mouse.getX(), love.mouse.getY())
  return inst
end
```

Answer (score 1):

After several hours (and only a few minutes after posting this question), I found a solution that works. Please note that this was coded in a "working file" rather than my actual cursor file, hence the name.

```
local working_file = {}

local cusorSprite

working_file.load = function(self)
  cursorSprite = love.graphics.newImage("assets/sprites/cursor.png")
  love.mouse.setVisible(false)
end

working_file.update = function(self)
end

working_file.draw = function(self)
  love.graphics.draw(cursorSprite, love.mouse.getX(), love.mouse.getY())
end

return working_file
```